# Tests: check if tuple is returned

Tags: erlang

I am writing a test which checks response from gen_server. The response itself is either `{profile, SomeProfileFromGenServer}` or `{error, ErrorResponse}`

So I wanted to write a test which does:

```
Profile = mygenserver:get_profile(),
?assertEqual(Profile, {profile, SomeProfile})
```

As I don't really care about the SomeProfile value. But this says that SomeProfile is unbound :( Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `?assertMatch`, with the first argument being a pattern:

```
?assertMatch({profile, _}, Profile)
```

Answer (score 2):

> assertMatch(GuardedPattern, Expr)

Evaluates Expr and matches the result against GuardedPattern, if testing is enabled. If the match fails, an informative exception will be generated; see the assert macro for further details. GuardedPattern can be anything that you can write on the left hand side of the -> symbol in a case-clause, except that it cannot contain comma-separated guard tests.

The main reason for using assertMatch also for simple matches, instead of matching with =, is that it produces more detailed error messages.

**Examples:**

```
?assertMatch({found, {fred, _}}, lookup(bloggs, Table))
?assertMatch([X|_] when X > 0, binary_to_list(B))
```